# Show that $\ell^1$ is non complete under $\ell^2$ norm

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences, complete-spaces

I'm trying to show that the metric space $ \ell^1$ is not complete under $\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty |x_k - y_k|^2\right)^{1/2}.$

So I'm trying find a non convergent cauchy sequence in $\ell^1$ w.r.t  $\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty |x_k - y_k|^2\right)^{1/2}.$

An example was given here [Non-convergent Cauchy sequence in $\ell^1$ with respect to the $\ell^2$ norm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1818343/non-convergent-cauchy-sequence-in-ell1-with-respect-to-the-ell2-norm) , but I dont seem to understand why it is not convergent in the $\ell ^1 space $.

My understanding is the sequence goes something like 
$(1 , \frac{1}{2} , \frac{1}{3}, ...... \frac{1}{k} , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , . . .  )$

The $d_{2}(x^n,x^m)$ ---> 0 for some large m,n where m > n so the sequence is obviously Cauchy.

However the sequence seems to converge to $0$ $\in \ell^1$. So I dont understand why this sequence is non convergent in $\ell^1$

Is this sequence correct? If not what is another example of a non convergent cauchy sequence in $\ell ^1$

If someone could clarify that would be appreciated

Comment: You should make sure you use $\ell$ and $L$ consistently. $\ell^p$ spaces are technically special cases of $L^p$ spaces, but for the latter, it is customary to specify the space and/or measure, and in any event, it is very confusing when you use both to refer to the same object. And by the way, LaTeX for $\ell$ is \ell.

Answer (score 1):

The example works. Indeed the limit is the harmonic sequence which does famously not belong to $\ell^1$.

For the sake of conventions, $\ell^p$ is used for sequences and $L^p$ for functions.

Comment: The harmonic sequence diverges so it doesn't belong in $l^1$. I was under the assumption that to prove a metric space $( X,d)$  to be non-complete you need to find a cauchy sequence IN $l^1$ and show it doesnt converge. The sequence doesnt belong in $l^1$ in the first place no? I dont understand  the relevancy in the 2 norm , where does comes into play here, is it just to show the sequence is cauchy?.

Comment: $x^n$ belongs to $\ell^1$ for all $n$ because it has finit support. So you have a sequence of elements of $\ell^1$ which converges to an element outside $\ell^1$. This is typical proof of incompleteness. But be careful that elements of $\ell^1$ are sequences themselves, so effectively $(x^n)$ is a sequence of sequences, which can be confusing.

Answer (score 0):

$(1,\frac 1 2 ,\frac 1 3,...,\frac 1 n,0,0...) \to (1,\frac 1 2 ,\frac 1 3,...)$ in $l^{2}$ so this sequence is Cauchy in $l^{1}$ with the $l^{2}$ norm. To show that it does not converge in $l^{1}$ use proof by contradiction: suppose it converges in $l^{2}$ norm  to some point $y$ in $l^{1}$. Then, for each $k$, the k-th coordinate of $x^{(n)}$ converges to the k-th coordinate of $y$. This implies that $y_k=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac 1 k =\frac 1 k$. But then $\sum |y_k|=\sum \frac 1 k =\infty$ which is a contradiction.